# Trouble exporting from Unity3D to Xcode

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, xcode, unity-game-engine

I've made a game in Unity3D(tried it in both Version 4.6 and 5) and it works perfectly fine in the engine. I then proceed to build the game to iOS, after setting all the appropriate settings. I then launch the build in Xcode(Version 6.4) and it opens up fine. The problem arises when I try to run the game, both on a simulator or on an eligible physical device (iPad running iOS 8). The build fails and I receive a code signing error. To be more specific the error I receive is:

`"Dependancy Analysis Error - Code Sign error. Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK iOS 8.2"`

I've gone through the setting, changed them to `Don't code sign`. Building it out of Unity as a development build doesn't help. Is there anything else I need to tweak in order to make it work?

Note: I do not have the paid apple developer membership yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an Apple Developer account in order to run your app on a non-jailbroken device.

As to why the iOS simulator isn't working, you need to change (in the Unity Editor):

Build Settings > Player settings > Other settings > SDK version to "Simulator SDK"

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hey, thanks for helping. In Build Settings, all I could find was 'Base SDK' for which there was no 'Simulator SDK option'. But your  comment reminded me of a build setting in Unity3d. Inside the engine, before building I just had to select 'Simulator SDK' in the Player Settings. After this the game runs in Xcode with 'iOS 8.2 SDK' selected. Pretty weird. But thanks a TON! Hope this also help anyone else out there stuck on the same problem. Cheers. :D

Comment: Yes, sorry those were the "Build Settings" I meant - in Unity. Glad it worked! (Edited my response for anyone else who has that problem)